# Parsing a json which contains duplicate keys

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to parse json with invalid structure which has duplicate keys using `Jackson` library. If a json has duplicate keys, I would like to extract them as a `Collection`.

Example of what I'm trying to parse (the actual json that I'm trying to parse comes from `Wireshark` json export):

```
{
    "a": "a",
    "a": {
        "b": {

        },
        "b": true
    }
}
```

However, since this json has duplicate keys, only the last value is retained:

```
JsonNode tree = new ObjectMapper().readTree(json);
System.out.println(tree); // {"a":{"b":true}}
```

I've also tried the `Guava` module which has `Multimap` support, however it doesn't work as expected for nested json objects.

Example using Guava module for the json that I have shown before:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new GuavaModule());
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);

Multimap read = mapper.readValue(json, Multimap.class);
System.out.println(read); // {a=[a, {b=true}]}
```

How should I tackle this problem using `Jackson` library? Are there any other libraries which would support parsing of such json structure for java?

Comment: Valid JSON doesn't have duplicate keys, so a parsing library shouldn't work the way you're asking

Comment: SyntaxError: Duplicate key 'a' on line 3

Comment: duplicate keys is valid json. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159 "The names within an object SHOULD be unique", not required to be unique.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I dunno. ECMA-404 (linked from json.org) says: "The JSON syntax does not impose any restrictions on the strings used as names, does not require that name strings be unique, and does not assign any significance to the ordering of name/value pairs. These are all semantic considerations that may be defined by JSON processors or in specifications defining specific uses of JSON for data interchange."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are flexible with json library you can make use of `net.sf.json.JSONObject`.

This library will retain the duplicated values by storing them into arrays. If multiple same keys are available it will create one key with all the values as Array.

And also the coding part is just a single line. Once you parsed the json using net.sf.json.JSONObject then you can supply this to jackson library.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject( "{ \"a\": \"a\", \"a\": { \"b\": {},\"b\": true}}" );

System.out.println( "net.sf.json.JSONObject: " + jsonObject );

JsonNode jsonNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree( jsonObject.toString() );

System.out.println( "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode" + jsonNode );
```

**Output:**

```
net.sf.json.JSONObject: {"a":["a",{"b":[{},true]}]}
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode{"a":["a",{"b":[{},true]}]}
```

**Maven dependency of `net.sf.json`**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is there a way we can remove the duplicates and keep it as a single object rather than an array

Comment: @AtulSoman Not possible as long as you are using duplicate keys.

Answer (score 3):

In the Jackson library you can read the JSON message token by token in a streaming way, then it would not eat anything from the message.

Comment: I believe that to be the only viable approach as well. There is some information to get started in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25426227/13075