# Parsing json with duplicate keys

Tags: java, json

I am trying to parse JSON file which contains duplicate keys in Java. I am using the method suggested in this answer [Parsing a json which contains duplicate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573120/parsing-a-json-which-contains-duplicate-keys).

The approach works fine if I hard-code the JSON but if I read it from a file,only the last duplicate key is read.

Code:

```
public class am {
    public static  void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();


        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("sample.json"));

        JSONObject a=JSONObject.fromObject(obj);
        JSONObject jsonObject=JSONObject.fromObject("{\n" +
                "  \"Data\": {\n" +
                "    \"A\": {\n" +
                "      \"B\": {\n" +
                "        \"C\": \"c\",\n" +
                "        \"D\": {}\n" +
                "      },\n" +
                "      \"E\": {\n" +
                "        \"F\": \"f\"\n" +
                "      },\n" +
                "      \"G\": {\n" +
                "        \"H\": \"h\"\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "    },\"A\": {\n" +
                "      \"B\": {\n" +
                "        \"C\": \"x\",\n" +
                "        \"D\": {}\n" +
                "      },\n" +
                "      \"E\": {\n" +
                "        \"F\": \"y\"\n" +
                "      },\n" +
                "      \"G\": {\n" +
                "        \"H\": \"z\"\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "    
                "\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}");
        System.out.println("Json objects are:::"+a);
        System.out.println("Json objects are:::"+jsonObject);
       
    }
}
```

Json File:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "A": {
      "B": {
        "C": "c",
        "D": {}
      },
      "E": {
        "F": "f"
      },
      "G": {
        "H": "h"
      }
    },"A": {
      "B": {
        "C": "x",
        "D": {}
      },
      "E": {
        "F": "y"
      },
      "G": {
        "H": "z"
      }
    },
    
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Json objects are:::{"Data":{"A":{"B":{"C":"x","D":{}},"E":{"F":"y"},"G":{"H":"z"}}}}
Json objects are:::{"Data":{"A":[{"B":{"C":"c","D":{}},"E":{"F":"f"},"G":{"H":"h"}},{"B":{"C":"x","D":{}},"E":{"F":"y"},"G":{"H":"z"}}]}}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do not have a constraint to use external JSON library than you can use `net.sf.json.JSONObject` to parse your JSON string, It will accept JSON with the duplicate key. It will retain the duplicated values by storing them into arrays.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject( "{\"Data\": {\"A\": {\"B\": {\"C\": \"c\",\"D\": {}},\"E\": {\"F\": \"f\"},\"G\": {\"H\": \"h\"}},\"A\": {\"B\": {\"C\": \"x\",\"D\": {}},\"E\": {\"F\": \"y\"},\"G\": {\"H\": \"z\"}}}}" );
System.out.println( "net.sf.json.JSONObject: " + jsonObject );
```

Comment: I am using that.But instead of hardcoding it,I want to read it from a file.When I do that I am unable to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stringify your JSON object

```
a.toString()
```

Comment: Still same result.

Comment: JSON works with a key - value approach. Keys are always unique, so it doesn't make sense to have duplicate keys.

Comment: I know but I have to work with a json with duplicate keys.